# How to change the foreground of selected ComboBoxItem with icon?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to change the foreground color of ComboBoxItem, however it doesn't work as expected.

The default color for the foreground is black, and I want to set selected item foreground to white when opening the dropdown/popup. It works fine when the ComboBoxItem contains only text content. However when ComboBoxItem including non-plain text content is selected, the foreground remains white after closing the dropdown/popup.

**Xaml:**

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}">
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Height="16" Width="16" Fill="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="123"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="456"/>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Height="16" Width="16" Fill="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="789"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

That displays as the following image:

Please find the below image for more information.

[image]

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true" SourceName="ToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out a solution by thinking backwards.

First I set the foreground of ComboBox to white when opening the dropdown/popup and make ComboBoxItem inherit the foreground color.

ComboBoxStyle:

> ```
> <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
>   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
> </Trigger>
> ```

ComboBoxItemStyle:

> ```
> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>
> ```

Then, I change the foreground color of unselected ComboBoxItem to black.

> ```
> <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
>   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
> </Trigger>
> ```

Here is the entire xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```